# Standalone Jetty Server Proxy is not working

Tags: eclipse, proxy, jetty, sapui5, jetty-8

We have developed a SAP UI5 web app using eclipse. In this app some cross domain ajax calls are there. That's why we are trying to use Jetty proxy.

While testing the app inside Eclipse(which actually uses inbuilt Jetty server) its running fine. But Whenever we are deploying the war file to Standalone Jetty server its not able to forward messages to target.

Can you please help how to configure Jetty proxy?
Below is the screenshot of web.xml inside my webapp.

[image: web.xml screenshot for Proxy]

Comment: Do you get an error message in your logs?

Comment: Its showing Timed out error. HTTP 500.

Comment: Isn't there anything useful in the server log? The time-out may indicate that the Jetty server is unable to reach the end-point.

Comment: @jpenninkhof its saying it couldn't connect end point.

Comment: In that case, something might be firewalled, perhaps the server can't resolved the URL or may need a proxy to communicate with the end-point. It's likely something in the network configuration.

Comment: @jpenninkhof, everything is working fine when I'm testing within Eclipse (i.e. Web App Preview). All ajax calls are getting executed correctly. But when Im running the app in standalone Jetty then problem is occurring.

Comment: From the same machine? Do you need to use a proxy to reach external sites?

Comment: @jpenninkhof Yes from same machine. And trying to use proxy to external site. But not working.

Comment: It looks like the proxy might be the culprit. Try using an internal endpoint to see if that works.

Comment: I noticed same issues after some upgrades. Not sure if Eclipse related upgrades, Windows related upgrades or SAP Eclipse Plugin related upgrades. I am using the WebAppPreview since 2 years (different Eclipse versions) but since some time I got more and more problems with it. Eclipse Mars was not working with the preview. Luna was working till one month ago (or so). But now I have timeouts as well.